# TypeError: "browser.notifications is undefined"?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Was messing around with Firefox browser extensions today, but came across an issue. I was trying out the notifications, but I am getting the error

> "TypeError: "browser.notifications is undefined"

My `manifest.json` is requesting the `notifications` permission. I am using `browser.notifications.create`

No notification is showing up.

Any ideas? Apologies if this is a simple question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I was trying to run the notification from my content script, didn't even realize. Notifications must be sent from a background script. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

To check the current permission

```
Notification.permission
```

To create Notification

```
 new Notification("Hi there!");
```

I recommend you have a look on the API first